# PrimeNG DataTable Horizontal Scrollbar Location

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I am having an issue working with PrimeNG DataTables. I have a table with a large number of columns that requires horizontal scroll. PrimeNG comes out of the box with horizontal scroll working with the scroll bar located below the table.

I need to make the scrollbar visible at all times similar to a browser scrollbar without requiring the user to scroll to the bottom of the table. I've attempted different CSS solutions using overflow-x properties, but they either don't work or ruin the PrimeNG table responsiveness.

Has anyone been able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says it can be achieved as follows:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars2" [scrollable]="true" [style]="{width:'500px'}">
```

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v8.2.9-lts/#/table/scroll

Answer (score -2):

use `[scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="100%" scrollWidth="100%"` in your `<p-table>` or `<p-dataTable>` tag

Comment: Swethnag Someshwar Sriramula's answer is working for me